# How to get term frequency and doc frequency from index produced by Lucene(version5.3)

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to get term frequency and doc frequency from index file produced by Lucene(5.3). The implementation is shown as below:

```
private static void showIndex(String iNDEX_DIR2) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("INDEX_DIR:" + iNDEX_DIR2);
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(iNDEX_DIR2).toPath()));

    int num_doc = reader.numDocs();
    System.out.println("number of docs: "+String.valueOf(num_doc));
    for(int docNum=0; docNum<num_doc; docNum++){
        Document doc = reader.document(docNum);
        System.out.println("Processing file:"+doc.get("id"));

        System.out.println("doc is null? "+ String.valueOf(doc==null));
        Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docNum, "content");
        TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
        BytesRef term = null;

        while((term = itr.next()) != null){
            try{
                String termText = term.utf8ToString();
                Term termInstance = new Term("contents",term);
                long termFreq = reader.totalTermFreq(termInstance);
                long docCount = reader.docFreq(termInstance);

                System.out.println("term: "+termText+", termFreq = "+termFreq+", docCount = "+docCount);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

When I run the snippet, I got the information:

```
INDEX_DIR:F:\Information Retrieval\project\TEST\INDEX
number of docs: 4
Processing file:null
doc is null? false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at IndexManager.showIndex
```

However, it show that the doc is not null.

May somebody help me with this problem?
Great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the NPE is thrown on:

```
TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
```

[`IndexReader.getTermVector`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector(int,%20java.lang.String)) returns null if the field was not stored with TermVectors, which [`TextField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html), for example, is not.

You can set a field to store TermVectors in the FieldType.  If you need a TextField with TermVectors, you can pass the FieldType for TextField into the FieldType constructor to create a mutable copy of it, for example:

```
FieldType myFieldType = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED);
myFieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);

doc.add(new Field("contents", fieldContents, myFieldType));
```

Comment: Actually, there is a field named "content". And if I invoke doc.get("content"), the program returns something.

Comment: Never said there wasn't.  I suspect that field was indexed *without TermVectors*.

Comment: So, what's the fieldContents?

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#Field(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType)